# jquery animate function works then reverses out it's change

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I've a div container with a list inside. The list is pretty big so I've restricted the height of of the container to 400px until a mouseover event occurs.

When the mouseover event occurs I run the following jquery

```
        $(".home-sidewidt").mouseover(function(){               

            if (!$(".home-sidewidt").hasClass("animation-run")) {
                $(".home-sidewidt").css("overflow", "visible");
                $(".home-sidewidt").animate({height:"1200px", queue: false},2000);
                $(".home-sidewidt").toggleClass("animation-run");
            }
        });
```

This expands the height of the list to 1200px and lets the user choose what they want. When the user clicks off the container anywhere else on the page I run the following:

```
        $('html').click(function() {
            if ($(".home-sidewidt").hasClass("animation-run")) {
                $(".home-sidewidt").animate({height:"400px", queue: false},2000);
                $(".home-sidewidt").css("overflow", "hidden");
            }
        });
```

This brings the height of the container back to 400px.

Now both of these pieces of code seem to work except after the user clicks off the list and it slides back to 400px, after about 3/4 seconds it rolls back out to 1200px. The fact that the duration before it rolls back is about the same as is specified in the animation I thought the 'open list' animation had run again but that doesn't appear to be the case when debugging.

I've experimented and if I click the page (not the list) 2 or 3 times the wait before the list re-expands is directly related to the number of times I've clicked. i.e. if I click 2 times it takes about 8 seconds, 3 times 12 seconds etc. It's a multiple of the animation duration.

I was going to do a jsfiddle for this but the list is using the superfish plugin and there are a number of css and .js files required and it seemed quite tricky.

Regards, sapatos

Comment: It's a lot more likely you'll get help here if you post an example on something like http://jsbin.com

Comment: Well, the first problem I see is that you forgot to remove the "animation-run" class in your second function, this explains why your open animation is not running second time. otherwise, I suggest uploading your code to jsfiddle (or similar site) so we can see it better

Comment: yeah, i realised that myself just now before seeing your comment. it made no difference however as it still wasn't working. I've removed the animation and it runs fine so I might leave it like that for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken what you had an put it in a plunker that also includes the solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/41eE6o?p=preview

First thing to change, you should use the different function signature for animate to use queue: false.

This:

```
$(".home-sidewidt").animate({height:"1200px", queue: false},2000);
```

Needs to be changed to this:

```
$(".home-sidewidt").animate({height:"1200px"}, {queue: false, duration: 2000});
```

Your inclusion of queue: false in the first parameter would be the incorrect part.  To still include queue: false use the two parameter form of animate where the second parameter is an object with the options.  See animate function signature arguments at the [jquery animate page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Second, the animate, when it is done, is changing the CSS overwrite style back to visible, which you can work around by adding your code to change the CSS style of overwrite to hidden into the complete callback that is fired when the animate is done, like this:

```
var animateOptions = {
    queue: false,
    duration: 2000,
    complete: function() {
      $(this).css("overflow", "hidden");
    }
};
$(".home-sidewidt").animate({height:"200px"}, animateOptions);
```

As I mentioned, all this code is detailed in the plunker, and I hope it is close to what you are looking for, but at least it should be easy to tweak.  I had to change some of the heights in the animations so it was easier to display within the plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/41eE6o?p=preview